# CSS Grid two rows nested in a single column

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking for a way to allow two rows within a single column while the other two columns to the right of it are equal/flexible to the height of those two rows. The width should be 100% when looking at all three columns (so around 33% each column). Here is an example of how I want it to look:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hM8F.png

I will be filling those boxes with clickable boxes like shown below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3dxq.png

I have tried using display: row, display: cell, but I am not able to add any margins to it so this is the product I get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1Gti.png

You can see that I have somewhat of the grid system set up, but not as ideally as I want it. There are no margins that can be set between the red and orange box, even though I am able to add margins to the turqoise and blue box.

Here is the code I have:

HTML:

```html
<div class='d-table'>
    <div class='t-row'>
        <div class='t-cell one-third'>
            <div class='turqoisebox'>
                Turqoise box here
            </div>
            <div class='bluebox'>
                Blue box here
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='t-cell one-third redbox'>
            Red box here
        </div>
        <div class='t-cell one-third orangebox'>
            Orange box here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.d-table {
    display: table;
}

.t-row {
    display: table-row;
}

.t-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    margin-left: unset;
    margin-right: unset;
    /*border: 1px solid tomato;*/
}

.one-third {
    width: 30%;
}

.two-thirds {
    width: 200px;
}

.bluebox {
    background-color: #9dd8dd;
    margin: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: solid #7dacb0;
    border-width: 3px;
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 8px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    transition: 0.3s;
    text-align: center;
}

    .bluebox:hover {
        box-shadow: 2px 8px 16px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    }
```

Any thoughts on how to replicate the second image results neatly?

Comment: Why not use CSS grid, as hinted by your own title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `flexbox`. Take a look at this simplified example:

```css
.content {
    background: orange;
    margin: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    flex: 1;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
}

.content > span {
    margin: auto;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: blue;
    flex: 1
}

.col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="content">
                <span>This is centered</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="content">
                <span>This is centered</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <div class="content">
            <span>This is centered</span>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            This is not
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            This is not
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <div class="content">
            This is not
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            This is not
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            This is not
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <span>This is centered</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could also use a minimal flexbox-based grid library like [Flexbox Grid](http://flexboxgrid.com/).

Comment: This is working the best! One more question, I am looking to vertically and horizontally align the text. I have tried adding ```css text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;``` but did not work nicely. Any thoughts?

Comment: You want to center the text in the divs?

Comment: Yes. I am placing text within the boxes shown in the second and third pic, but it is aligning to the top left. When I use ```text-align: center;```, it brings the text to the center horizontally but I am also looking to do it vertically as well. The vertical centering is the main issue. Thanks again!

Comment: I made an edit. I added `display: flex` to `.content`, and added a new rule `.content > span { margin: auto; }`.

Comment: That worked, this question is solved. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hey Francisco, actually it seems like the ```margin: auto;``` is only working for horizontal alignment. The vertical alignment does not seem to be working when I tried it on the red and orange big boxes. I only thought it was working vertically as I had tested it on the smaller blue and turqoise boxes. Regardless, the "verticalness" of the text is still unchanged and text is still at the top of the boxes. Any ideas for the vertical alignment so the text is directly in the middle of the boxes?

Comment: Nevermind, I used ```padding: 25%;``` on the content and it worked out! Fingers crossed this does not cause any issues later on haha!

Comment: Make sure the `content` class has the `display: flex` property or the `margin: auto` of the inner span won't do anything

Comment: Hey Francisco, ```margin: auto``` didn't seem to work for me but was able to figure it out with the padding. But now a new issue has come up where the boxes do not seem to stack upon each other when the resolution is lowered (mobile view). Here is what it looks like: https://i.imgur.com/OaVIOhf.png

I'd like it to look like this:
https://i.imgur.com/98096xP.png

Any thoughts on the properties? Shouldn't flex handle that automatically?

Comment: @SagarPatel That's a topic for another question. Search for "responsive content with flexbox"

Answer (score -1):

Margin is used for setting where elements should start so instead use padding between those 2 elements to get the space you want.

Comment: You should provide at least an example of what you are explaining

Comment: Yes, I could not understand your thoughts.

Comment: I answered this on the way 2 college i had no time to make an example.